# Get a control from DataGridTextColumn without searching through the whole DataGrid children

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I have a textbox inside a datagrid header.

I am trying to get its content when clicking on a totally unrelated button elsewhere in the page (cannot use selectedItem).

Was able to implement it using the below code.

XAML :

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" >
             <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>      
                        <TextBox Name="txtName"/>                                                                 
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
       </DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C# :

```
TextBox MyTextbox = FindChild<TextBox>(dataGrid, "txtName");
MessageBox.Show(MyTextbox.Text);

public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            T childType = child as T;

            if (childType == null)
            {
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;

                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    if (foundChild != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

By using this above method I am able to get the Textbox 'txtName' from the Template. But I am afraid with more columns and more data the search might get heavy.

I tried to find the row which contains the header so that search can be run only on the row but it was not successful.

Is there any better and efficient way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to get the `TextBox`'s text, you could databind the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType={x:Type local:MyWindow}},
                                        Path=TheTextBoxValue}"/>
```

This example assumes that the grid has an ancestor called `MyWindow` in the XAML `local` namespace, and that this window has a string valued property called `TheTextBoxValue`.

Then, you always have access to the `TextBox`´s value and you do not need to search the logical tree of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since I have multiple columns I think this method would be a bit difficult. Is there any way to Bind the text to a variable in a class?

Comment: With "variables", do you mean C# fields? Binding to fields is not possible; you can only bind to dependency properties or to normal C# properties.

Comment: i was able to bind the text to a string in my parent class.
public String TheTextBoxValue{ get; set; }. Thank you!!!!